# Key presses are often not registering until another key is pressed

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur

Wondering if anyone has seen this before.  It happens across a number of apps, and I've disabled everything that I thought could be causing it like Karabiner.

I'll be typing and often a keypress will not register until I press another key.  e.g. if I'm typing `fox` and type <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, only `f` shows up.  I can wait 30 seconds, and it still shows `f`.  I type <kbd>x</kbd> and it suddenly shows `fox`

It's especially annoying when it happens with <kbd>return</kbd> and terminal ignores me until I hit <kbd>return</kbd> again (or anything else).

Any ideas at all on how to debug this?

OSX 11.5.2, 2019 Macbook Pro 16"

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I have the same macbook pro and this issue has been haunting me.

Comment: Nope.  I even re-installed OSX.  I think it might be a hardware problem because it was happening right after with literally nothing else installed

Comment: I have had this same problem on my 16" 2019 pro and it has not gone away for years. Fresh installation of Sonoma and it still does it. I've heard discussions of keystrokes going through the T2 chip for security reasons and I wonder if there's something up with it.